# jQuery setInterval Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, setinterval, tablesorter

How can I sort my data with plugin `Tablesorter`? I update my table with new data every "n" milliseconds.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 setInterval(foo, 10000);
 foo();
 function foo () {$('#tda').load('# #tt');}
    $("#tt").tablesorter({
    widgets: ["zebra"],
    sortList:[[2,0]]
    });
});
```

My page structure is:

```
<div id="tda">
  <table id="tt">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>updated data...<tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

But this data is not sorted.

Comment: As a heads up (and a reason why it may not be working right now), you seem to have misspelled `thead` (and have it incorrectly as `theaf`)

Comment: The documentation even has an example for it. http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html

Comment: How can i sort those autoupdating data?

Comment: Simple tablesorter is working [code: $(document).ready(function() { $("#tt").tablesorter({sortList:[[2,0]]});});] Or simple autoupdate table-page is workink too [code: $(document).ready(function() {setInterval(foo, 10000); foo(); function foo () {$('#tda').load('# #tt');}});] But Itsn`t working all togathe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tablesorter should be called within the [load callback function](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function):

```
$(function() {
 setInterval(foo, 10000);
 foo();
 function foo () {
  $('#tda').load("mysite.php", function() {
    $("#tt").tablesorter({
      widgets: ["zebra"],
      sortList:[[2,0]]
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It works! $(function() {
 setInterval(foo, 10000);
 foo();
 function foo () {
  $('#tda').load("# #tt", function() {
    $("#tt").tablesorter({
      widgets: ["zebra"],
      sortList:[[2,0]]
    });
  });}
});